# Fastlane script execution

Tags: fastlane

I am trying to execute the lanes which are declared in the Fastfile.ios files, but i am getting below error. Could any one please help me out.

An error occurred while executing the `error` block:
Could not find action, lane or variable 'current_action'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions

Comment: It is really difficult to help you without additional information. Please post your configuration, the command you ran and the output.

Comment: bundle exec fastlane

Comment: [19:08:35]: Welcome to fastlane! Here's what your app is set up to do:
+--------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                         Available lanes to run                          |
+--------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Number | Lane Name                       | Description         |
+--------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+
| 1      | decrypt  
| 2      | get_env 
| 3      | prep_deployment 
| 4      | ios list_apps

Comment: i have selected the lane number
[19:08:35]: Which number would you like run?
4

Comment: After selecting the lane it has been asked for apple id and pwd and provided. After providing the username and password got the below error.
 An error occurred while executing the `error` block:
Could not find action, lane or variable 'current_action'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions

Comment: Post the content of your Fastfile here.